# Display vba code output in particular cell & sheet in active worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub get_cookie()
MsgBox (GetCookie("https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY"))
End Sub
```

Thanks!!!

I have written these codes for getting cookies from the website. But I want this cookie in my active worksheet.

Comment: _in my active worksheet._ ? Which particular cell or does it not matter ?

Comment: `Range("A1") = YourFunctionHere()`